# отправка на почту значение выбранного чекбокса

Tags: jquery, checkbox

На форме при выборе `checkbox`  `"Нанесение краски"` нужно отправить на почту `Краска name="Краска" и значение id="price"`.

```js
//отправка значений на почту:
function PutToHidden() {
  //цена покраски 
  let span = document.getElementById('price');
  let hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
  hidden.value = span.textContent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onSubmit="PutToHidden()">
  <label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски</label>
  <span id="price">2500</span><input type="hidden" name="Краска" id="hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Краска" id="yslygi" />
</form>
```

Тут не правильно прописала,приходит значение даже если не выбираешь на странице.

Comment: `if ($('#yslygi').is(':checked')) { ... }`

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev на почту приходит Краска on. Не видит цену...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставляйте значение `hidden` только если чекбокс активен:

```js
function PutToHidden() {
  if ($('#yslygi').is(':checked')) {
    let span = document.getElementById('price');
    let hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
    hidden.value = span.textContent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onSubmit="PutToHidden()">
  <label for="yslygi">Нанесение краски</label>
  <span id="price">2500</span><input type="hidden" name="Краска" id="hidden" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="Краска" id="yslygi" />
</form>
```

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо!!!